# ::first-letter does not count `@` and apply css in 2 letters

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

while playing around [::first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

when string start with `@` then it color 2 letters.

```css
 footer {
 color: mediumseagreen;
 font-size: 2rem;
 font-style: italic;
}
footer::first-letter { color: purple; }
```

```html
<footer>@xyz</footer>
<footer>xyz</footer>
```

is this right behavior?

Comment: The documentation you linked to seems to pretty clearly explain why. Also, what does "apply cdd" mean?

Comment: css* typo again :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per MDN,

> [Punctuation that precedes or immediately follows the first letter is
> included in the match.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) Punctuation includes any Unicode character
> defined in the open (Ps), close (Pe), initial quote (Pi), final quote
> (Pf), and other punctuation (Po) classes.

The `@` character is part of the "[Other Punctuation](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Po)" category, so it is correct for `@x` to be highlighted in your first example.